# Does AM26C32 leave outputs floating?

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet

Does the AM26C32 leave outputs floating, by which I mean, when "off", is the output pulled to GND, or would I need to provide a pull-up/down resistor?

Where in the datasheet would this info be specified?

Answer (score 0):

This is specified in section 8.4.1: Device Functional Modes, Enable/Disable:

[image]

The last row, corresponding to both enables driven with a disable input, shows that the output is not driven ('Z').

Comment: If the outputs are tri-state, doesn't that mean that when the IC is enabled, Low outputs are tied to GND?

Comment: @19172281 If you keep the device enabled, you will not need a pulldown. The only scenario under which a powered AM26C32 will float its output is when you set both enables to disabled. If you just want logic low/high, keep the device enabled at all times.

Answer (score 0):

It reads on the first datasheet page that it has three-state outputs so they would be floating, not grounded.

Comment: Right, so to feed the outputs into an MCU, I would need to provide pull downs? I'm using the AM26C32 to turn the differential output of a quadrature encoder into a single ended output which I can use with my MCU's QEI.

Comment: Only if you disable it, you might need pull-downs or pull-ups. Unless the MCU has internal pull-ups. Why would you disable it?

Comment: You would disable the receiver if you have the output of multiple devices connected together, in a bus arrangement.  Then you only want one of the n devices driving the bus at a time.  This use is referenced in the opening paragraph of the data sheet.

Comment: Sure, I know that, that's why I asked the OP why in the given quardature reader scenario the chip output would ever need disabling as keeping it always enabled means no external resistors are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I wouldn't say the outputs are left floating, because they are **clamped** with diodes. Quite likely with Schottky diodes, because the output may not exceed V<sub>CC</sub> + 0.5.

Note the upper diode is forward baised when Vcc = 0, so, depending the current injected to the output pin (most likely noise, so, small current), the output will be 0V (for no to small currents) up to max 0.3V - 0.4 V.

Comment: The outputs on the Pin Functions table are described as Logic Level Outputs, which suggests that they are not left floating. Is that right?

Comment: @19172281 How can \$\bar{G}\$ be HIGH when Vcc is 0V?

Comment: @19172281 Moreover, the title of the chapter is containing the table is Device **Functional** Modes. I doubt this apples when Vcc=0.

Comment: @19172281 Mmm, I assumed that *"when "off","* meant the device not being powered. Maybe you'd better clarify that in the original question.

Comment: The outputs are not in the same configuration when "OFF" (powered off) and tri-stated (high Z).  When powered off, the output levels are clamped (as mentioned above) to ~0+0.3V and ~GND-0.6V, so that in a bus topology other devices can not drive the bus.  When powered but tri-stated, the outputs are clamped to ~Vcc+0.3V and ~GND-0.6V, and so other devices can drive the bus properly.

Comment: To add to the confusions, the data sheet uses the term "OFF" in one place and equates that to the powered, tri-state configuration, table 6.5